# Hide Html Tag When Null

Tags: reactjs

I want to wrap html tags around react state value when the value is not null, ie.

```
{this.state.keyword!=null?' '+'<span>'+this.state.keyword+'</span>'+' ':''}
```

but now, the page renders  even the this.state.keyword is blank. How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "page renders even the this.state.keyword is blank"?

Comment: Do you use JSX?

Comment: oh, It shows html tags on the webpage, such as <span></span>...

Comment: That means, this.state.keyword is not `null` (?) Maybe it's `undefined`.

Comment: You could reverse the conditional and ask if keyword is defined 
`{ this.state.keyword ? <span>{this.state.keyword}</span> : null }` which means, if this.state.keyword is not null or undefined, render the span, otherwise render null.

Answer (score 1):

Use `!this.state.keyword` instead of `this.state.keyword!=null`

`!this.state.keyword` will check for all falsy values, like `null`, 0, empty string (not undefined though)

```
{!this.state.keyword ? '' : '<span>'+this.state.keyword+'</span>'+' '}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this code is inside render{return( {this.state.keyword!=null?' '+'<span>'+this.state.keyword+'</span>'+' ':''} )} section.

Comment: You can still use it inside a render method

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by :

```
{ this.state.keyword? ' '+'<span>'+this.state.keyword+'</span>'+' ':''}
```

Explanation : in your code you're checking for null only whereas you can check for all falsy conditions (eg null, undefined, empty string, 0 and false) by using above condition

Comment: I guess that you just wrote something without explaining why it helps?

Comment: @Abhay Sehgal your solution works for the textbox but not the dropdown box. If I have a dropwdown Subject, {this.state.subject?' '+'<span>'+this.state.subject+'</span>':' '}, the page does not display this.state.subject value.

Comment: What is the value of subject at the time of render?

Comment: this.state.subject value is ACC, BIO, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Duh, I moved  tag out of the curly brace like this {this.state.keyword!=null?' '+this.state.keyword+' ':''} and solve the problem. Thanks everyone.